# Checkboxes and Javascript: Inconsistent click event + selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a couple of toggle buttons for Highcharts in Angular. However, my question is more of a general javascript question and not about Angular or Highcharts since I've seen this problem pop up when working in strictly jQuery with checkboxes as well.

Here is my problem: When toggling checkboxes, I sometimes click the outer edge of the checkbox or have another dropdown open nearby and find that the box state does not change although the function on the click fires anyway.

For example, if you open a nearby bootstrap dropdown box and then click a checkbox while the dropdown is open, the input checkbox acts weird and does not change the state but still fires the intended function.

In order for the checkbox correct itself thereafter, I have to re-toggle the button for the state to match the function that is supposed to fire on that state.

Here is a small video clip that illustrates my example:

http://screencast.com/t/YRaDchstI

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check1" ng-click="toggleGrp(check1)" value="{true: check1 == true}">
```

Despite using  value="{true: check1 == true}" as a failsafe in determining if the box is in the checked state or not, the results are inconsistent.

Is there something I can do in JS to stop this, or will this require more of a hack on my part? I'm thinking if I can't fix the issue, I'll have to create an invisible box that sits on top of the buttons and becomes displayed when the nearby dropdown box is open.

Comment: Can you change the behaviour of `toggleGrp` so that it sets properties based on the value of the checkbox, rather than on the previous property value? That is, effectively make it `setGrpFromCheckboxValue(check1)` instead of `toggleGrp(check1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that if I toggle the scope from a button, I can trigger the input checkbox remotely and the button behaves the same with or without an expanded dropdown nearby.

```
<button type="button" class="btn"
  ng-click="check1 = !check1"
  ng-class="{active: check1}"></button>

<input type="checkbox"
  ng-model="check1"
  ng-click="toggleGrp(check1)"
  style="visibility: hidden;">
```